# Convexity on a direction

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

In "Ming-Jun Lai, Larry L. Schumaker. *Spline Functions on Triangulations*.
Cambridge University Press, 2007, p.72." we have:

> A function $f$ defined on a triangle $T$ is said to be convex in the
>   direction $u$ provided
>   $$\frac{f(w_3)-f(w_2)}{|w_3-w_2|} \ge \frac{f(w_2)-f(w_1)}{|w_2-w_1|}$$
>   for all ordered sets of points
>   $w_1, w_2, w_3$ in $T$ lying on a line pointing in the direction of
>   $u$. We say that $f$ is convex on $T$ provided it is convex in all
>   directions. As is well known from calculus, if $f$ has two derivatives
>   in the direction $u$, then this definition of convexity in the
>   direction $u$ is equivalent to $D_u^2f(v)\ge 0$, all $v\in T$.

But All thing that we have about function convexity briefly is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function.

I can't make a connection between definition of convex function and convexity of a function on a certain direction, also both of them with second directional derivative of function on a direction. How we can proof that usual definition of convex function and "We say that $f$ is convex on $T$ provided it is convex in all directions." are equivalence? What's proof of "If $f$ has two derivatives in the direction $u$, then this definition of convexity in the direction $u$ is equivalent to $D^2_uf(v)\ge 0$, all $v\in T$."?

A link to a comprehensive source is pleasured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different questions.

**Question 1 :**

($f$ is convex) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($f$ is convex all the directions)

**Question 2 :**

If $f$ has two derivatives, then ($f$ convex in the direction $u$) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($D^{2}_{u} (f) (v) \geq 0$, $\forall v \in T$)

**For the first question.**

One only needs to recall the definition of convexity.

$f$ is called convex if $\forall x_{1} ,x_{2} \, \forall t \in [0,1] : f (t x_{1} + (1-t)x_{2}) \leq t \, f (x)_{1} + (1-t) \, f (x_{2})$

$(\Rightarrow)$ : We choose an arbitrary direction $u$ and three points $w_{1}$, $w_{2}$ and $w_{3}$ aligned in this direction and in this order. We define the number $t$ as

$$ t = \frac{|w_{3} - w_{2}|}{|w_{1} - w_{3}|} $$ Since the points are aligned in the order $w_{1}$, $w_{2}$ and $w_{3}$, we have $t \in [0,1]$. Moreover, we note that we have $w_{2} = t \, w_{1} + (1-t) \, w_{3}$. Applying the usual definition of convexity, we obtain:

$$ f (w_{2}) \leq \frac{|w_{3} - w_{2}|}{|w_{1} - w_{3}|} f (w_{1}) + \frac{|w_{1} - w_{2}|}{|w_{1} - w_{3}|} f (w_{3}) $$

so that we have

$$ \frac{|w_{1} - w_{3}|}{|w_{1} - w_{2}| |w_{3} - w_{2}|} \, f (w_{2}) \leq \frac{f(w_{1})}{|w_{1} - w_{2}|} + \frac{f (w_{3})}{|w_{3} - w_{2}|} $$

The final step of the calculation is to note that $|w_{1} - w_{3}| = |w_{1} - w_{2}| + |w_{2} - w_{3}|$ since the points are aligned in the good order, and after rearrangement, we find back the expression for the definition of the convexity in the direction $u$.

($\Leftarrow$) : Completely similar. One just needs to redo this reasoning in the other way. (Is it clear or do you need more details ?)

**For the second question.**

The idea is that as soon as you have given yourself a direction $u$, you are back to the case of a $1D$ function. Indeed, for a given direction $u$ and a given *starting point* $v_{0}$, you need to study the convexity of the function

$$\begin{aligned}
f_{u , v_{0}} : &\mathbb{R} \to X
\\
& t \mapsto f (v_{0} + t \, u)
\end{aligned} $$
The usual criteria of convexity for twice differentiable function imposes you $f_{u , v_{0}} '' \geq 0$. The final remark is to note that $f_{u , v_{0}} '' (t) = D^{2}_{u} f \, (v_{0} + t u) $, so that the equivalence of the two properties is immediate.

Comment: OK, I got it, thanks @jibe.